# C# generics -- why do lambdas work, when simple methods don't?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm having trouble understanding why the C# compiler can infer types for

```
Array.ConvertAll(new int[1], i => Convert.ToDouble(i));
```

but not for

```
Array.ConvertAll(new int[1], Convert.ToDouble);
```

when it would seem that the former would be a more complicated deduction than the latter.

Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Waiting for Jon Skeet.

Comment: I'm not following -- both versions work fine for me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @KirkWoll: Oh maybe it's because I'm on VS 2008? Are you on 2010?

Comment: I can confirm it works well on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Yeah, works for me in LinqPad, and (in VS2010) .Net 3, 3.5, and 4.

Comment: I believe there were type inference changes between C# 3 and 4 but I cannot find the specifics right now; hopefully Mr. Skeet or Mr. Lippert will chime in?

Comment: The second version [works fine on Mono 2.8](http://ideone.com/ufesk).

Comment: Could you include the exact compiler error you're seeing on VS2008?

Comment: just as a guess, does the second work if you replace it with a method that doesn't have non-int overloads?

Comment: Actually the second method is already a lambda expression. The second has only an implicit argument. If you look at the signature of the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53 (both are handled by the same method).

Comment: @JamesManning: well Mehrdad uses a static class that has a list of predefined convert operations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx). When the array is one of these types, it will succeed.

Comment: @KirkWoll et al - the framework version isn't relevant, it's the compiler version which produces the problem. So issue will only be present in VS2008 AFAIK.

Comment: Also - I think you'll find your answer in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Comment: @RJLohan: Indeed, please post that as an answer! (lol Eric answered my question before I even posted it...)

Comment: @CommuSoft: No, the method call *doesn't* include a lambda expression. It uses a delegate, but that delegate is created from a method group conversion. Lambda expressions are just another way of creating delegates or expression trees.

Comment: @Jon Skeet If I'm right lambda calculus is just some syntactical sugar. The compiler (or runtime environment) will create a class representing the function and insert it as an instance?

Comment: @CommuSoft: Lambda *calculus* doesn't really come into it - but yes, lambda *expressions* are "just" syntactic sugar. Sometimes the compiler needs to create another class, sometimes it doesn't, depending on what's captured. But that doesn't make your claim that the second form uses a lambda expression any more valid - it simply doesn't. Both use delegates, but only the first version uses a lambda expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is pretty well covered in this (archived) blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

In summary as I understand it (should the link ever vanish); this was a conscious design decision in C# 3.0, in that it was not appropriate to perform type inference on Method Groups (your second example).

I guess quite a few folks didn't like that, so the issue was resolved for C# 4.0 (as of Visual Studio 2010);

"In C# 4.0, return type inference works on method group arguments when the method group can be associated unambiguously with a completely fixed set of argument types deduced from the delegate. Once the argument types associated with the method group are known, then overload resolution can determine unambiguously which method in the method group is the one associated with the delegate formal parameter; we can then make a return type inference from the specific method to the delegate return type."